# Circle pager indicators in RecyclerView don't have a fixed position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using this class as item decoration in a horizontal RecyclerView (#2), that is also included in a vertical recyclerView(#1):

```
holder.recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new CirclePagerIndicatorDecoration());
```

CirclePagerIndicatorDecoration.java:

```
public class CirclePagerIndicatorDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private int colorActive = 0xDEE54242;
    private int colorInactive = 0x33000000;

    private static final float DP = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    private final int mIndicatorHeight = (int) (DP * 16);
    private final float mIndicatorStrokeWidth = DP * 4;
    private final float mIndicatorItemLength = DP * 4;
    private final float mIndicatorItemPadding = DP * 8;
    private final Interpolator mInterpolator = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();
    private final Paint mPaint = new Paint();

    public CirclePagerIndicatorDecoration() {
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(mIndicatorStrokeWidth);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.onDrawOver(c, parent, state);

        int itemCount = parent.getAdapter().getItemCount();

        // center horizontally, calculate width and subtract half from center
        float totalLength = mIndicatorItemLength * itemCount;
        float paddingBetweenItems = Math.max(0, itemCount - 1) * mIndicatorItemPadding;
        float indicatorTotalWidth = totalLength + paddingBetweenItems;
        float indicatorStartX = (parent.getWidth() - indicatorTotalWidth) / 2F;

        // center vertically in the allotted space
        float indicatorPosY = parent.getHeight() - mIndicatorHeight * 2F;

        drawInactiveIndicators(c, indicatorStartX, indicatorPosY, itemCount);

        // find active page (which should be highlighted)
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) parent.getLayoutManager();
        int activePosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        if (activePosition == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
            return;
        }

        // find offset of active page (if the user is scrolling)
        final View activeChild = layoutManager.findViewByPosition(activePosition);
        int left = activeChild.getLeft();
        int width = activeChild.getWidth();
        int right = activeChild.getRight();

        // on swipe the active item will be positioned from [-width, 0]
        // interpolate offset for smooth animation
        float progress = mInterpolator.getInterpolation(left * -1 / (float) width);

        drawHighlights(c, indicatorStartX, indicatorPosY, activePosition, progress);
    }

    private void drawInactiveIndicators(Canvas c, float indicatorStartX, float indicatorPosY, int itemCount) {
        mPaint.setColor(colorInactive);

        // width of item indicator including padding
        final float itemWidth = mIndicatorItemLength + mIndicatorItemPadding;

        float start = indicatorStartX;
        for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {

            c.drawCircle(start, indicatorPosY, mIndicatorItemLength / 2F, mPaint);
            start += itemWidth;
        }
    }

    private void drawHighlights(Canvas c, float indicatorStartX, float indicatorPosY,
                                int highlightPosition, float progress) {
        mPaint.setColor(colorActive);

        // width of item indicator including padding
        final float itemWidth = mIndicatorItemLength + mIndicatorItemPadding;

        if (progress == 0F) {
            // no swipe, draw a normal indicator
            float highlightStart = indicatorStartX + itemWidth * highlightPosition;

            c.drawCircle(highlightStart, indicatorPosY, mIndicatorItemLength / 2F, mPaint);

        } else {
            float highlightStart = indicatorStartX + itemWidth * highlightPosition;
            // calculate partial highlight
            float partialLength = mIndicatorItemLength * progress + mIndicatorItemPadding*progress;

            c.drawCircle(highlightStart + partialLength, indicatorPosY, mIndicatorItemLength / 2F, mPaint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
        outRect.bottom = mIndicatorHeight;
    }
}
```

There is an issue with this code.

When scrolling down recyclerView #1, the circle indicators from recyclerView #2 are not always shown at the same place in recyclerview #2 .

Example: Item 1 from recyclerView #1 and circle pager indicators from item 1 from recyclerView #2.

[image]

Example: Item 5 from recyclerView #1 and circle pager indicators from item 1 from recyclerView #2.

[image]

And a second question is how to change the position from the circle indicators to the top side of the recyclerView #2.

EDIT: RecyclerView #1 layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardview1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:padding="10dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="16dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"

            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_24dp"
            card_view:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
            card_view:civ_border_width="2dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"

            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/profile_image"
            android:text="Sample"
            android:textColor="@color/grey_700"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtUsername"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/txtUsername"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/profile_image"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_deportes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/txtUsername"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtUsername"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp1"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/skate" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp6"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/layout_deportes"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/skate" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp2"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/skate" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp3"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/skate" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp4"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/skate" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp5"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/skate" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp7"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/skate" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp8"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/skate" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/profile_image"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:minLines="3"
            android:paddingRight="40dp"
            android:text="Vivimos rodeados de objetos cotidianos que, a pesar de verlos cada día, todavía no tenemos muy claro para qué sirven. Es el caso del cuadrado con dos ranuras que tienen algunas mochilas, el bolsillo pequeño de los vaqueros, sus remaches de cobre e incluso las siglas 'YKK' que aparecen en tu cremallera. ¿Alguna vez te habías preguntado para qué sirven los agujeros laterales de algunas zapatillas?    "
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/addUser"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/layout_deportes"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/home_add_user" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tres"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/addUser"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/home_submenu" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivAmbassador"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/profile_image"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/profile_image"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/home_ambassador" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/spot_sport"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtDescription"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/skate" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tipo_spot"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtDescription"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/spot_sport"
            android:fadeScrollbars="true"
            card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/negocio" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/spot_map"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtDescription"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tipo_spot"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tipo_spot"
            android:fadeScrollbars="true"
            android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
            card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/home_pin_mapa" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spot"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtDescription"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/verified"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/spot_map"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:text="Skatepark Macba, Barcelona, Spain"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/verified"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/spot_map"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/txtVerified"
            card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/home_ambassador" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtVerified"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/verified"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-18dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
            android:text="Verified"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
            android:id="@+id/slider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="280dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/spot_sport"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:visibility="gone" >

        </com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerMarcas"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/spot_sport" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fire"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/recyclerMarcas"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/home_fire_activado" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/comments"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/recyclerMarcas"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fire"
            card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/home_comentarios" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fixpin"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/recyclerMarcas"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/comments"
            card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/home_check" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtEstadoAqui"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/recyclerMarcas"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/fixpin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fixpin"

            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:lines="2"
            android:text="He estado aqui"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtComments"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/recyclerMarcas"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/fixpin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/fireresult"

            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtEstadoAqui"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:lines="2"
            android:text="10 comments"
            android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fireresult"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/recyclerMarcas"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/home_fire_activado" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: I noticed it's not your circle indicator that changes position but the views above it. Add to your post the XML of recyclerView (#1) list item

Comment: @GiddyNaya, of course, but it is a bit large.

Comment: @GiddyNaya, done. XML put on post.

Comment: Also add to your post the item XML for recyclerView (#2).

Comment: I'm suspecting the ImageViews inside recyclerView (#2) are miscalculated by the UI maybe due to usage of wrap or fill_parent. Try specifying a fixed size for the imageView like 250dp if that may be the case.

Comment: @GiddyNaya, thank you, but I have found a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue just putting the circle indicator at the top of the recyclerView.

```
float indicatorPosY = 40;
```

Now its position doesn't change at any item.